# Losing number of pages with errors when parsing pages in vuejs3 (bootstrap-vue3)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I have a .vue file, which I copied from the site: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination
code :

```html
<template>
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="items"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        perPage: 3,
        currentPage: 1,
        items: [
          { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
          { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
          { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I don't understand why when every time I press PRE, the page count gradually decreases and the elements on the table become empty. Does anyone have any solution to help me. Thanks for all the replies

I hope you guys can help me with that

Comment: What do you mean with "every time I press PRE"? What is PRE?

Comment: Pre is back to the previous page, ie every time I press like that, 1 page after that will be lost, if I keep pressing PRE continuously, there is no page left